# Finding nearest black pixel from center of contour in OpenCV and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I would like to find a point from the center of the contour to a point that is the nearest black pixel or non-contour pixel. I would like to create a straight line from the center to that point. Here's is my current codes:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include<Windows.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void on_trackbar(int, void*);
void createTrackbars();
void morphit(Mat &img);
void toggle(int);

const int MAX_NUM_OBJECTS = 500;

const int FRAME_WIDTH = 900;
const int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;

const int MIN_OBJECT_AREA = 20 * 20;
const int MAX_OBJECT_AREA = FRAME_HEIGHT*FRAME_WIDTH / 1.5;

Point middle;

int l_MIN = 30;
int l_MAX = 165;
int a_MIN = 139;
int a_MAX = 165;
int b_MIN = 136;
int b_MAX = 172;

int kerode = 2;
int kdilate = 5;

bool domorph = true;
bool showchangedframe = true;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    createTrackbars();
    on_trackbar(0, 0);

    int x, y;
    Mat frame, labframe, rangeframe;
    Mat newframe, newrf;
    int key;
    //VideoCapture cap(0);

    while ((key = waitKey(30)) != 27)
    {
        toggle(key);
        frame = imread(argv[1], 1);
        newframe = imread(argv[1], 1);
        //cap >> frame;
        //cap >> newframe;
        //flip(frame, frame, 180);
        //flip(newframe, newframe, 180);
        newframe = Scalar(0, 0, 0);
        cvtColor(frame, labframe, COLOR_BGR2Lab);
        inRange(labframe, Scalar(l_MIN, a_MIN, b_MIN), Scalar(l_MAX, a_MAX, b_MAX), rangeframe);
        newrf = rangeframe.clone();

        int largest_area = 0;
        int largest_contour_index = 0;
        vector<vector<Point> > contours;

        findContours(newrf, contours, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        vector<Moments> mu(contours.size()); //get moments
        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            mu[i] = moments(contours[i], false);
        }

        vector<Point2f> mc(contours.size()); //get centers
        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            mc[i] = Point2f(mu[i].m10 / mu[i].m00, mu[i].m01 / mu[i].m00);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) //iterate through each contour. 
        {
            double a = contourArea(contours[i], false);  //Find the area of contour

            if (a>largest_area)
            {
                largest_area = a;
                largest_contour_index = i;                //Store the index of largest contour
            }
        }

        drawContours(newframe, contours, largest_contour_index, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), CV_FILLED);
        circle(newframe, mc[largest_contour_index], 5, CV_RGB(255, 255, 0), -1, 8, 0);

        imshow("Detected", newframe);

        if (showchangedframe)
            imshow("Camera", frame);

        else
            imshow("Camera", rangeframe);
    }
}

void on_trackbar(int, void*)
{
    if (kerode == 0)
        kerode = 1;
    if (kdilate == 0)
        kdilate = 1;
}

void createTrackbars()
{
    String trackbarWindowName = "TrackBars";
    namedWindow(trackbarWindowName, WINDOW_NORMAL);
    createTrackbar("l_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &l_MIN, l_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("l_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &l_MAX, l_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("a_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &a_MIN, a_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("a_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &a_MAX, a_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("b_MIN", trackbarWindowName, &b_MIN, b_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("b_MAX", trackbarWindowName, &b_MAX, b_MAX, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("Erosion", trackbarWindowName, &kerode, 31, on_trackbar);
    createTrackbar("Dilation", trackbarWindowName, &kdilate, 31, on_trackbar);
}

void morphit(Mat &img)
{
    erode(img, img, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(kerode, kerode)));
    dilate(img, img, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(kdilate, kdilate)));
}

void toggle(int key)
{
    if (key == 'r')
        showchangedframe = !showchangedframe;
}
```

My output goes by the following
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9TJW.jpg)

What I want is to create the following:
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcRrS.jpg)

Thanks in advance..much help is needed.

Comment: Why don't you extract the edge map of the image, then check for the minimum `Euclidean distance` between the center and the white pixels along the edge map?. The point with the minimum distance would give you what you want. You probably have to move the point by a pixel (up/down/left/right), to be precise.

Comment: @RickM. Or dilate the image before finding the contour rather than trying to figure out which direction to move.

Comment: @RickM. thanks for the advice. Sorry but how would you suggest I extract the edge map?

Comment: You can run a `Canny`edge detector on the L channel of the image OR `cvtColor` on frame from BGR2GRAY and run it on the gray scale image

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the [distance transform](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs664/2008sp/handouts/cs664-7-dtrans.pdf) topic.

You will get a map that contains for each pixel the coordinate of the nearest contour using the distance type you want (L1, L2, ...).

There is a tutorial in OpenCV for [`distanceTransform()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga8a0b7fdfcb7a13dde018988ba3a43042): [Image Segmentation with Distance Transform and Watershed Algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/dbd/tutorial_distance_transform.html).